# pydantic custom hypothesis build

Tags: python, pydantic, hypothesis-test

### Problem in a nutshell

I am having issues with the hypothesis `build` strategy and custom pydantic data types (no values are returned when invoking the build strategy on my custom data type.

### Problem in more detail

Given the following pydantic custom type, which just validates if a value is a timezone.

```py
import pytz
from pydantic import StrictStr

TIMEZONES = pytz.common_timezones_set


class CountryTimeZone(StrictStr):
    """Validate a country timezone."""

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield from super().__get_validators__()
        yield cls.validate_timezone

    @classmethod
    def validate_timezone(cls, v):
        breakpoint()
        if v not in TIMEZONES:
            raise ValueError(f"{v} is not a valid country timezone")

        return v

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(examples=TIMEZONES)
```

When I attempt to use this in some schema...

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: CountryTimeZone
```

and subsequently try to build an example in a test, using the [pydantic hypothesis plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/hypothesis_plugin/) like.

```py
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st

@given(st.builds(Foo))
def test_something_interesting(schema) -> None:
    # Some assertions
    ...
```

`schema.bar` is always `""`.

### Questions

1. Is there something missing from this implementation, meaning that values like `"Asia/Krasnoyarsk"` aren't being generated? From the documentation, examples like `PaymentCardNumber` and `EmailStr` build as expected.
2. Even when using `StrictStr` by itself, the resulting value is also an empty string. I tried to inherit from `str` but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Came across the same problem today. Seems like the wording in the [hypothesis plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/hypothesis_plugin/) docs give the wrong impression. Pydantic has written [hypothesis integrations](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/master/pydantic/_hypothesis_plugin.py#L136) for *their* custom types, not that hypothesis supports custom pydantic types out of the box.

Here is a full example of creating a custom class, assigning it a [test strategy](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.register_type_strategy) and using it in a pydantic model.

```py
import re
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st
from pydantic import BaseModel

CAPITAL_WORD = r"^[A-Z][a-z]+"
CAPITAL_WORD_REG = re.compile(CAPITAL_WORD)


class MustBeCapitalWord(str):
    """Custom class that validates the string is a single of only letters
    starting with a capital case letter."""

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        # optional stuff, updates the schema if you choose to export the
        # pydantic schema
        field_schema.UPDATE(
            pattern=CAPITAL_WORD,
            examples=["Hello", "World"],
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError("string required")
        if not v:
            raise ValueError("No capital letter found")
        elif CAPITAL_WORD_REG.match(v) is None:
            raise ValueError("Input is not a valid word starting with capital letter")
        return cls(v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MustBeCapitalWord({super().__repr__()})"


# register a strategy for our custom type
st.register_type_strategy(
    MustBeCapitalWord,
    st.from_regex(CAPITAL_WORD, fullmatch=True),
)


# use our custom type in a pydantic model
class Model(BaseModel):
    word: MustBeCapitalWord


# test it all
@given(st.builds(Model))
def test_model(instance):
    assert instance.word[0].isupper()
```